# Paste multiple files while excluding first column

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a directory with 100 files of the same format:

```
> S43.txt

Gene    S43-A1   S43-A10  S43-A11  S43-A12
DDX11L1 0       0       0       0 
WASH7P  0       0       0       0
C1orf86 0       15      0       1 



> S44.txt

Gene    S44-A1   S44-A10  S44-A11  S44-A12
DDX11L1 0       0       0       0 
WASH7P  0       0       0       0
C1orf86 0       15      0       1
```

I want to make a giant table containing all the columns from all the files, however when I do this:

```
paste S88.txt S89.txt | column -d '\t' >test.merge
```

Naturally, the file contains two `'Gene'` columns.

1. How can I paste ALL the files in the directory at once?
2. How can I exclude the first column from all the files after the first one?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `join` with the --nocheck-order option:

```
join --nocheck-order S43.txt S44.txt | column -t
```

(the `column -t` command to make it pretty)

However, as you say you want to join *all* the files, and join only takes 2 at a time, you should be able to do this (assuming your shell is bash):

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
files=(*.txt)

cp "${files[0]}" result.file
for file in "${files[@]:1}"; do
    join --nocheck-order result.file "$file" | column -t > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" result.file
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I exclude the first column, though? (in all files after the first one)

Comment: join takes care of that for you

Answer (score 5):

If you're using `bash`, you can use **process substitution** in `paste`:

```
paste S43.txt <(cut -d ' ' -f2- S44.txt) | column -t
Gene     S43-A1  S43-A10  S43-A11  S43-A12  S44-A1  S44-A10  S44-A11  S44-A12
DDX11L1  0       0        0        0        0       0        0        0
WASH7P   0       0        0        0        0       0        0        0
C1orf86  0       15       0        1        0       15       0        1
```

`(cut -d$'\t' -f2- S44.txt)` will read all but first column in `S44.txt` file.

To do this for all the file matching `S*.txt`, use this snippet:

```
arr=(S*txt)
file="${arr[1]}"

for f in "${arr[@]:1}"; do
   paste "$file" <(cut -d$'\t' -f2- "$f") > _file.tmp && mv _file.tmp file.tmp
   file=file.tmp
done

# Clean up final output:
column -t file.tmp
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I can merge all files in the directory at once while excluding the first column in all but the first one?

Comment: Strange... for some reason it still includes the first column for every file... might there be another way to specify not to?

Comment: Never mind -- just changed the delimiter to `-d$'\t'` . Works perfectly now. Thanks!